# Add Pagination on Custom Post Type Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I've moved custom posts on what would normally be an archive template over to a dedicated page template.  I've been following this article:
https://jasonyingling.me/use-page-custom-post-type-archive-url-rewrites/.

But I'm confused about how I would add in pagination.  If I inspect the code $paged is now always 0.  When I call the code I've got here (`<?php pagination(); ?>`, nothing renders.

```
function pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query in the pagination function does not include your custom post type. Look at the [Example With a Custom Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), where a category is set in the arguments. Also look how `$paged` is set.